# How to make a backwards button in a GUI work for a search engine in Eclipse

Tags: user-interface, button, javafx

I can't figure out how to make a back button function from going to one webpage to another through a created search engine in Eclipse

I cannot find anything that will work

The results would be that when you enter a website then another one you would be able to go back to the first website from the said second website

Comment: Assuming you're talking about web pages in WebView you want `webEngine.executeScript("history.back()");` you can read more about it in the "evaluating javascript" on the WebEngine javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html

Comment: Take a look at [`WebHistory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebHistory.html).